# How to create a rank on two columns in python polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

Suppose we have this dataframe in polars (python):

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {   
        "era": ["01", "01", "02", "02", "03", "03"],
        "pred": [3,5,6,8,9,1]
    }
)
```

I can create a rank/row_number based on one column, like:

```
df.with_columns(rn = pl.col("era").rank("ordinal"))
```

But if I want to do it based on two columns, it is not working:

```
df.with_columns(rn = pl.col(["era","pred"]).rank("ordinal"))
```

I get this error message:

```
ComputeError: The name: 'rn' passed to `LazyFrame.with_columns` is duplicate
Error originated just after this operation:
DF ["era", "pred"]; PROJECT */2 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried with `struct`?

Answer (score 5):

Using multiple selectors inside a single `pl.col` call:

```
pl.col("one", "two").function()
```

is essentially short-hand for:

```
pl.col("one").function(), pl.col("two").function()
```

You can use [pl.struct](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.struct.html#polars.struct) to "combine/group" multiple columns together:

```
>>> df.with_columns(rn = pl.struct("era", "pred"))
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ era ┆ pred ┆ rn        │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ i64  ┆ struct[2] │
╞═════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ 01  ┆ 3    ┆ {"01",3}  │
│ 01  ┆ 5    ┆ {"01",5}  │
│ 02  ┆ 6    ┆ {"02",6}  │
│ 02  ┆ 8    ┆ {"02",8}  │
│ 03  ┆ 9    ┆ {"03",9}  │
│ 03  ┆ 1    ┆ {"03",1}  │
└─────┴──────┴───────────┘
```

Which you can then `.rank`

```
>>> df.with_columns(rn = pl.struct("era", "pred").rank("ordinal"))
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬─────┐
│ era ┆ pred ┆ rn  │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64  ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 01  ┆ 3    ┆ 1   │
│ 01  ┆ 5    ┆ 2   │
│ 02  ┆ 6    ┆ 3   │
│ 02  ┆ 8    ┆ 4   │
│ 03  ┆ 9    ┆ 6   │
│ 03  ┆ 1    ┆ 5   │
└─────┴──────┴─────┘
```

Comment: And what if you want this rank to be by "era" ascending and by "pred" descending ordered?

Comment: multiply it by -1. So instead of `pl.struct("era", "pred")` do `pl.struct("era", pl.col("pred")*-1)` If the underlying column wasn't numeric then you'd do a rank first ie  `pl.struct("era", pl.col("pred").rank()*-1)`